# How to properly display special characters in excel 2003 file

Tags: excel, encoding, utf-8, special-characters, html-entities

I have an excel 2003 spreadsheet contining special characters like `á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ`. The problem is that they are displayed with their HTML entity codes.

So instead of

`Almócita`

`Gádor`

I see

`Alm&oacute;cita`

`G&aacute;dor`

and so on.

How can i save/re-encode the file so that is displays properly the special characters?

CSV/Open Office/Excel file formats are all acceptable as long as the characters are properly displayed.

**UPDATE:** The excel file is uploaded for reference [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81dbe6e1cs9y478/bbdd_municipios.xls?dl=0)

Comment: Where does the file come from? My bet is you aren't dealing with an actual Excel spreadsheet but a HTML file posing as one.

Comment: I got the file one year ago and really do not remember where it came from. I have uploaded the file here if it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/81dbe6e1cs9y478/bbdd_municipios.xls?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lot of searching and considering options like importing the sheet in MySQL and fixing the values via PHP, I finally decided to do it the old fashioned dummy like way - I made a filter to show only cells that contain `&` and then via Find/Replace I replaced all HTML entity codes with their respective characters. The whole operation took about 15 min, which is noting compared to the time I spent searching for alternative soluton.